# Color issue in badge icon in next badge section

Tags: bug, design, badges

When hover the badges in the Next badge section I see the badge icon color issue.

1. For Silver badge, if The progress bar is in-progress normally I can see the silver badge icon. If I hover on the bar the icon is very hard to see due to the color code
2. For Gold badge, if the progress bar is in-progress normally I can't see the gold badge icon. But if I hover on the bar I can able to see that icon.

The same is recorded and shared below:

[image: Hover on Badges - color issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed after the design changes in the [activity tab](/a/351378/). So now when hover on the badges in the next badge tracker, it's looking fine.

GIF for the reference:

[image: New design change for next badge tracker]

Comment: I spent 5 minutes watching this. Thank you

Comment: @AlonEitan Oh, LOL :)